# How we can sort numbers lexicographically without converting them to strings in C language?

Tags: c

I have tried to sort the numbers using dictionary sort with converting them to strings.But I don't know how to sort numbers using dictionary sort without converting them to strings

Comment: Are these positive numbers we are talking about?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about positive numbers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: show us some code.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the largest power of 10 (the number of digits of your biggest number)
2. Write your compare function so it does a comparison between

   a * 10 ^ (max_digits - a_digits) and b * 10 ^ (max_digits - b_digits)
3. Apply any sort algorithm you wish with this comparison function.

Comment: I think this approach takes more time and complexity

Comment: If you use a regular comparison based sort your time complexity is going to be this sort's complexity. All the pre-computation can be done in O(N).
As of space complexity it's likely going to be O(N) as well.

So yes, you lose some space complexity with this solution.

Comment: I also don't see how that sorts lexicographically. Say the numbers are 1, 12, 3 and 9 (max digits is therefore 2), 1 * 10 * (2-1+1)=20, 12*10*(2-2+1)=120, 3*10*(2-1+1)=60 and 9*10*(2-1+1)=180. This would sort 1, 3, 12, 9 which doesn't make sense either lexicographical or in natural order.

Comment: Yes, this compare function doesn't work

Comment: My bad, it's not supposed to be a multiplication but an exponentiation.

Comment: @MehakLakhanpal: Of course this approach is more expensive than simple numeric comparison; that's because lexicographic comparison is more complicated than numeric comparison when the data is stored as numbers and not strings (but numeric comparison is more expensive than lexicographic comparison when the numbers are stored as strings). Using the 'wrong' representation imposes a cost. You can take a hit and do the 'conversion to string' once per data point and then use the cheap lexicographic comparison on the strings, or you can pay the cost of conversion for every comparison. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Every value will be compared at least once, so there'll be some computational cost for each element.  You can determine the digits in each number before starting the sort, again reducing the per-comparison cost. Which is better depends on how big the data set is, and whether memory limits are going to be an issue.  You can reduce cost by using more space to store more data to reduce the cost of comparison.

Comment: If I do comparison based on digits of numbers,this can be lengthy process if numbers contains large no. of digits